# How does Lambdaj having work?

Tags: java, lambdaj

I am learning LambdaJ and everytime I need to achieve a task I have to check at existing examples and modify them in order to use lambdaj.

I have started using it but I think I'm missing something here that would like to ask you.

I'm not clear about using `having` method. I don't understand how it works and how I can I use it.

I have debugged, decompiled and read its documentation but I don't find the "way of thinking" lambda.

`having` javadoc says:

> static  HasArgumentWithValue    having(A argument,
>   org.hamcrest.Matcher matcher)
>
> Creates an hamcrest matcher that is
>   evalued to true if the value of the given argument satisfies the
>   condition defined by the passed matcher.

I've used `having` in examples like this:

```
List<User> result = filter(having(on(User.class).getAge(), greaterThan(20)), list);
```

I understand that `having` applies a harmcrest matcher to an argument and repeats that all over the list.

But my question is how does having works? How do I think in a functional way on lambdaj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your code could look like this:

```
the function filter take each user from list and 
 apply it over function having 
   that retrieved the age and compare with value of 20.
```

This can be wrote as

```
private List<User> filter(List<User> users) {
    final List<User> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for(User user : users) {
       if(having(user.getAge(),greaterThan(20)) {
          filtered.add(user);
       }
    }
    return filtered;
}


private boolean having(Integer age,  org.hamcrest.Matcher<Integer> matcher) {

   return matcher.matcher(age);
}
```

In other words function having take an two arguments, a value and matcher and evaluate the matcher against value. And the value argument is passed by function filter that expect boolean in result.